# Creating excel file: ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font while spring apps startup

Tags: java, excel, spring-mvc, apache-poi, classnotfoundexception

I am developing an application to export objects into an excel. When I tested as standalone application its working fine. But when I moved the same code to my spring service class then my webapp is failing due to the ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font and ClassNotFoundException: Iorg.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet. I am not using Maven or gradle for building. I manually copied all the required jar files to the build path in eclipse.
[image]

Does anyone knows why its failing? whats the cause? Am i missing something?

Find the stacktrace below:

```
    WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bugzillaReportController': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'deferralReportService': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.myapp.bugzillareport.service.DeferralReportService] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: BugzillaReport
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@5acf9800
]
May 30, 2018 10:39:15 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bugzillaReportController': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'deferralReportService': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.myapp.bugzillareport.service.DeferralReportService] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: BugzillaReport
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@5acf9800
]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1348)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4627)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5091)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'deferralReportService': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.myapp.bugzillareport.service.DeferralReportService] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: BugzillaReport
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@5acf9800
]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:262)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:513)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:484)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:618)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:318)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.myapp.bugzillareport.service.DeferralReportService] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: BugzillaReport
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@5acf9800
]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:659)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:556)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:245)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Font
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:641)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1292)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1121)
    ... 64 more
```

And find below the code used for creating excel file:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

        // Create a Sheet
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Deferral_Excel");

        // Create a Font for styling header cells
        Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
        headerFont.setBold(true);
        headerFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 12);

        // Create a CellStyle with the font
        CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        headerCellStyle.setFont(headerFont);

        // Create a Row
        Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);

        String[] columns = { "BugID", "Product", "Component", "Bug Status", "Bug Severity", "Assigned to", "Summary",
                "Deferral Justification" };

        // Create cells
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(i);
            cell.setCellValue(columns[i]);
            cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
        }

        // Create Other rows and cells with employees data
        int rowNum = 1;
        for (Bug bug : bugzillaReport.getBugs()) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue(bug.getBug_id());
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(bug.getProduct());
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue(bug.getComponent());
            row.createCell(3).setCellValue(bug.getBug_status());
            row.createCell(4).setCellValue(bug.getBug_severity());
            row.createCell(5).setCellValue(bug.getAssigned_to());
            row.createCell(6).setCellValue(bug.getShort_desc());
            row.createCell(7).setCellValue(bug.getDeferralJustification());
        }

        // Write the output to a file
        FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
        try {
            fileOut = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath);
            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();

            // Closing the workbook
            workbook.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Tomcat needs access to the libraries... Add these libraries to the lib-folder of tomcat

Comment: @Wufo It worked when I moved the files to tomcat lib folder. Thanks a lot. :-)

But I was wondering, this is a workaround or is there any other proper manner to do so. Also, why tomcat was not able to access the jar even though I have added them to the project build path?